# AuthUI Firebase 4.0.1 - Cannot Resolve Symbol 'getInstance'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm attempting to follow [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui#sign_in) to authenticate logins but receive "Cannot resolve symbol 'getInstance'" on the AuthUI line.

```
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;

// ...

// Choose authentication providers
List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
    new AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build());

// Create and launch sign-in intent
startActivityForResult(
    AuthUI.getInstance()
        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
        .setAvailableProviders(providers)
        .build(),
    RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Firebase app dependencies include:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.0.1'
```

The import pulled in for AuthUI is listed as:
`import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;`

These docs are for Firebase UI Auth 4.0.0, and with my version being 4.0.1 I can't see why there's an issue.

I've cleaned and rebuilt the project but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was to do with my app Gradle file.

When following docs I was to add the following to my app Gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
       // ...
       resConfigs "en" // And any other languages you support
    }
```

I placed this as a stand-alone block rather than integrating it in the existing `defaultConfig` block. Amending this removed errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this too in your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.2'
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I had that previously. Added again, but no success.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you post stack trace too :)

Comment: There is no stack trace - the program is not being run. The IDE shows it cannot resolve the symbol.

Comment: In which method are you executing your code? Maybe it's IDE error. Have you tried clearing Android Studio cache?

Comment: The code isn't being executed. This is Android Studio where it highlights syntactic and semantic errors without compilation. I have invalidated cache and restarted. No success.